# A Lowenheim-Skolem-like Result for Structures of Set Theory

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

While reading Kanamori's proof (page 59-60 in $\textit{Higher Infinite}$) that $\kappa$ is $\Pi_1^1$-indescribable if and only if $\kappa$ is weakly compact; it appears that he uses the following result:

Let $\bar R$ denote a new predicate symbol. If $\kappa$ and $\alpha$ are inaccessible, there there exists a transitive $X \supsetneq V_\alpha$ such that $|V_\alpha| = |X|$, and $\langle X, \in, R \cap X \rangle \prec \langle V_\kappa, \in, R \rangle$, where of course $R$ is the interpretation of $\bar R$ in $V_\kappa$ and $\prec$ denote elementary substructure.

A Skolem Hull argument is one way of proving the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem for structures in general. However the problem is simultaneously making $|X| = |V_\alpha|$ and making $X$ transitive.

For instance a possible approach is to take any $X_0' \supsetneq V_\alpha$ with $X_0' \subseteq H(\alpha^+)$ and $|X_0'| = \alpha$. (Here $H(\delta)$ are the sets with transitive closure with cardinality less than $\delta$. ) Let $X_0$ be the transitive closure of $X_0'$. $|X_0| = \alpha = \beth_\alpha = |V_\alpha|$ since $\alpha$ is inaccessible. Taking the Skolem hull with respect to some complete set of Skolem functions in $V_\kappa$, one gets $H(X_0) \prec V_\kappa$. Let $X_1' = H(X_0)$. Then $|X_1'| = \alpha = |V_\alpha|$. $X_1'$ may not be transitive. One can try to let $X_1$ be the transitive closure; however, then $|X_1|$ may not be $\alpha$.

If one could pick Skolem functions such that every Skolem function restricted to $X_0$ has range lying in $H(\alpha^+)$, then $X_1$ define above would still have cardinality $\alpha$. Is this possible to find such Skolem function where the rank is bounded. Equivalently for any formula, when the other parameters lie in $V_\beta$, can quantification over $V_\kappa$ be replace by quantification over the sufficiently small $V_\gamma$ for $\gamma < \kappa$. If this is possible, I believe iterating the Skolem Hull construction and transitive closure, $\omega$-times and taking the union in the end will produce the desired elementary substructure.

Can this be done? Is there an alternative way to prove this transitive Lowenheim Skolem type result? Is this result even true? Thanks for any clarifications.

Comment: Have you tried iterating Skolem-hull$\to$transitive closure $\omega$ times?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mentioned this. If the range of some skolem function applied to some tuple elements of $X_0$ lies in for example $H(\alpha^{++}) - H(\alpha^+)$, then taking the transitive closure after the Hull will have cardinality greater than $|V_\alpha| = \alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can get such an $X$, even if there is no $R$ to worry about.  Suppose you had an $X$ as in the question.  Since $X$ properly includes $V_\alpha$, it has elements of rank $\geq\alpha$.  Since the rank function is absolute for transitive models, $X$ contains the rank of such a set; in particular it contains an ordinal $\geq\alpha$, and, being transitive, it contains $\alpha$.  Being an elementary submodel of $V_\kappa$, $X$ must contain all elements of $V_\kappa$ that are definable in $V_\kappa$ from $\alpha$.  In particular, $X$ must contain $\alpha^+$ (and $\alpha^{++}$, etc.); but then to be transitive, $X$ must have cardinality at least $\alpha^+$ (and more), contrary to the requirement that $|X|=|V_\alpha|=\alpha$.

Comment: Then what does the author mean exactly by an "iterated Skolem hull argument"?

Comment: @1830rbc03 The iterated Skolem Hull argument is and $\omega$-step iteration of the construction of $X_1$ in the preceding paragraph of the question.

Comment: I thought your answer shows that does not work, or did I misunderstand something? Do we really need $X$ to be transitive anyway? If we have a $X$ then we can collapse it to a transitive set $X'$; since $X$ contains $V_\alpha$ it is identity on $V_\alpha$. $X'$ may not be an elementary substructure of $V_\kappa$ (taking $R$ into consideration it may not even be a substructure) but we still get a contradiction to the assumption that $V_\alpha$ cannot be extended, do we?

Comment: @1830rbc03 Yes, my answer shows that what was proposed in the question doesn't work. As to whether "we really need $X$ to be transitive", transitivity is part of what the question requires. A non-transitive $X$ doesn't answer the question, and the transitive collapse of such an $X$ doesn't either because it won't be an elementary submodel of $V_\kappa$. Such an $X$ might well suffice for Kanamori, since the question says only that he "appears to use" this information.

Answer (score 0):

The following edited answer (hopefully) gives an $X$ of size $\alpha^{+}$.

Define $\langle X_i : i < \alpha^{+} \rangle$ as follows. $X_0 = V_{\alpha} \cup \{\alpha\}$. For $0 < i < \alpha^{+}$, $X_i$ is the transitive collapse of an elementary substructure $Y_i$ of $(V_{\kappa}, \in , R)$ of size $\alpha$ containing $\bigcup \{X_j : j < i\}$. Put $X = \bigcup \{X_i : i < \alpha^{+}\}$. Note that $X_i$'s are increasing and for a club no. of stages $i < \alpha^{+}$, we have $(X_i, \in, R \cap X_i)$ is an elementary substructure of $(X, \in, R \cap X)$. Now fix any $a_1, \dots, a_n \in X$, and suppose $(X, \in, R \cap X) \vDash \phi(a_1, \dots, a_n)$. Let $i < \alpha^{+}$ be large enough to include all $a_1, \dots, a_n$. Let $j > i$ be a limit stage such that $(X_j, \in, R \cap X_j)$ is elementary substructure of $(X, \in, R \cap X)$. Then $(X_j, \in, R \cap X_j) \vDash \phi(a_1, \dots, a_n)$. Let $\pi: Y_j \rightarrow X_j$ be the collapsing map used at stage $j$. Since $\pi$ fixes the transitive kernel of $Y_j$, it fixes $a_1, \dots a_n$. So $(Y_j, \in, R \cap Y_j) \vDash \phi(a_1, \dots a_n)$ hence also $(V_{\kappa}, \in, R) \vDash \phi(a_1, \dots, a_n)$.

More edit: Now for some $i < \alpha^{+}$, $(X_i, \in, R \cap X_i) \prec (X, \in, R \cap X) \prec (V_{\kappa}, \in, R)$ and $|X_i| = \alpha$ so that we are done.

Comment: Why is there a club set of $i$ such that $X_i$ is an elementary substructure of $X$? Am I correct to assume that $Y_j$ denote the elementary substructure of $(V_k, \in, R)$ which you Mostowski collapsed to $X_j$?

Comment: Also in the definition of elementary substructure, if $M \prec N$, then $M$ should be a subset of $N$ and the elementary embedding needs to be the inclusion map. I am worried that you can not prove any of the $X_i$ are elementary substructure of $X$ since the embedding may not be inclusion (since you use the Mostowski collapse as one of your isomorphisms at each stage).

Comment: You are right, I wasn't thinking straight. Although, notice that if I stretch the construction to length $\alpha^{+}$, I do get an $X$ of size $\alpha^{+}$.

Comment: I edited to get the weaker conclusion.

Comment: I probably fixed the proof. Do you see any holes now?

Comment: I still don't see why many (or even any) of the $X_i$ are  elementary submodels of $X$. For example, since $\kappa$ is inaccessible (and presumably $>\alpha$), each $Y_i$ will contain $\alpha^+$ (as it's definable from $\alpha$ in $V_\kappa$), but the collapsing maps are likely to send $\alpha^+$ to different elements of $X_i$ for different $i$. If that happens, then these $X_i$ can't be elementary submodels of the same $X$, since they disagree about what the successor cardinal of $\alpha$ is.

Comment: For any $i < \alpha^{+}$, let $j_i > i$ be large enough so that $X_{j_i}$ contains contains all witnesses to $\alpha$ many existential formulas $(\exists x) \phi(x, a_1, \dots, a_n)$ with parameters $a_1, \dots, a_n \in X_i$ that are true in $X$. Then taking the supremum of $i, j_i, j_{j_i}$ etc. shouldn't we get an elementary substructure of $X$? Maybe I'm missing something.